# Iterator returns an Object and not the desired object

Tags: java, object, iterator

```
public class Facture {
private Client client = new Client();;
private float Paiement;
private float soustotal;
private float tps;
private float tvq;
private float ttc;
private List<LigneFacture> lignesFac = new ArrayList<LigneFacture>();

public Facture(){
    this.Paiement=0;
    this.soustotal=0;
    this.tps=0;
    this.tvq=0;
    this.ttc=0;

}
public Client getClient() {
    return client;
}

public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}

public float getPaiement() {
    return Paiement;
}

public void setPaiement(float Paiement) {
    this.Paiement = Paiement;
}

public float getSoustotal() {
    return soustotal;
}

public void setSoustotal(float soustotal) {
    this.soustotal = soustotal;
}

public float getTps() {
    return tps;
}

public void setTps(float tps) {
    this.tps = tps;
}

public float getTvq() {
    return tvq;
}

public void setTvq(float tvq) {
    this.tvq = tvq;
}

public float getTtc() {
    return ttc;
}

public void setTtc(float ttc) {
    this.ttc = ttc;
}

public List<LigneFacture> getLignesFac() {
    return lignesFac;
}
public void addLignesFacture(LigneFacture ligneFac){
    this.lignesFac.add(ligneFac);
    Iterator iter_lignesFact = lignesFac.iterator();

    while(iter_lignesFact.hasNext()){
       LigneFacture lignefac_cur =  iter_lignesFact.next();
    }
}
```

}

Hi i have this class, problem is in the last method, Java tells me that iter_lignesFact returns an Object value and not LigneFacture value, and thus he wants me to cast it to LigneFacture, why is that ? I defined my iterator on a list of LigneFacture.

Answer (score 14):

You've used the raw type here:

```
Iterator iter_lignesFact = lignesFac.iterator();
```

You want to use the generic form:

```
Iterator<LigneFacture> iter_lignesFact = lignesFac.iterator();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used a raw type, but you can avoid the trouble of typing entirely, and a lot of code, by using a foreach loop:

```
for (LigneFacture lignefac_cur : lignesFac) {
    // do something with lignefac_cur
}
```

Using a foreach loop is a very tidy way if iterating. Note though that whole iterating using thus kind of loop, you may not alter the collection. Specifically, there is no equivalent of `iterator.remove()` available. However, if you don't need this kind of operation in your loop, foreach is the preferred syntax.

Answer (score 0):

And, you don't want to use `Iterator` at all. What us the function doing?

```
public void addLignesFacture(LigneFacture ligneFac){
    this.lignesFac.add(ligneFac);
    Iterator iter_lignesFact = lignesFac.iterator();

    while(iter_lignesFact.hasNext()){
       LigneFacture lignefac_cur =  iter_lignesFact.next();
    }
}
```

First, it adds `ligneFac` to the list `lignesFac`. `ligneFac` is now the last member of the list, barring a bizarre threading situation. Then, the iterator is created, and `lignefac_cur` is set to each member in turn, stopping at the last member, which is `ligneFac`.  So, why not simply set `lignefac_cur` to `ligneFac`?  But then, you throw away `lignefac_cur`.  I assume that you have shortened the method you originally wrote.

```
public void addLignesFacture(LigneFacture ligneFac){
    this.lignesFac.add(ligneFac);

    LigneFacture lignefac_cur =  ligneFac;
    // Do things with lignefac_cur.
    // You might want to make it an instance variable instead,
    // or even to have a method currentLigne() that gets the last
    // member of the list. You might even want to use
    // Stack or Queue as being more expressive.
}
```